# Перенос слова на другую страницу

Tags: перенос

Есть ли в русском языке правила касательно переноса на другую страницу? По-моему, это выглядит не очень удобочитаемо, когда начало слова расположено в правом нижнем углу одной страницы, а конец - в левом верхнем углу другой. Однако каких-то конкретных правил на этот счёт я не нашёл. LaTeX переносит слова таким образом. Имеет ли смысл пытаться отучить его от этого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А этих правил и нет.Вот, например, рекомендации при вёрстке книги:

http://edu.jobsmarket.ru/library/design/10630/

О ПЕРЕНОСЕ СЛОВ
В целях достижения ритмически-правильных промежутков между словами при наборе не следует широко соблюдать всех академических правил переноса слов с одной строки на другую, достаточно придерживаться существующих на этот счет основных правил грамматики. Но следует избегать по возможности таких переносов, где отделяются тесно связанные между собой слова, напр. Глава / II, Людовик / XVI, 1925 / год, И. И. / Иванов.
При процессе чтения наш ум так быстро усваивает прочитанное, что даже рискованные переносы, конечно, грамматически правильные, - не мешают этому усвоению.

Я с Вами согласна, нужно печатать так, чтобы было удобно читать, но если кто-то не хочет проявлять такую вежливость, мы не имеем права требовать её, как и заставить кого-то здороваться с Вами. **Советовать кому-то можно, а требовать - нет.**

А вот о переносах строк рекомендации строже:
О ПЕРЕНОСАХ СТРОК
Совершенно недопустимы как оставление внизу страницы одной строки нового абзаца, так и перенос на следующую страницу одной конечной в абзаце, „висячей" строчки. Нехорошо, если переносят и две конечные строки абзаца, особенно если последняя строка меньше половины строки. Лучше вогнать набор на одной или двух предыдущих страницах, что почти всегда возможно. Если невозможно - лучше уничтожить переборкой какой-либо абзац. Наиболее удобное и оптически оправданное начало новой страницы - с абзаца, но оно редко удается.

Answer (score 0):

Правил нет, есть соображения удобочитаемости. А оно сильно отличается у разных групп.

Даже если вы возьмете, например, текст на английском, то там свои правила верстки. Впрочем, в компьютерную эру верстка стало занятием довольно рутинным, переделать легко и просто. Поэтому считаю правильным руководствоваться не только ценными указаниями вышестоящих органов, но и собственным пониманием вопроса. Я, конечно, не стал бы переносить слово в конце страницы. Хотя, помнится, попадались изданные в прежние времена книги с таким переносом. Я такие вещи почему-то запоминал хорошо, иной раз больше чем содержание прочитанного.